# How to cycle for dynamic JObjects in another JObject?

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net, .net-3.5

Actually i'm am processing some JSON data get from some API in an old VB.NET project in Framework 3.5

I'm stuck in the processing of the following response:

```
{
  "data": {
    "89359": {
      "name": "A",
      //...
    },
    "89360": {
      "name": "B",
      //...
    }
  }
}
```

Each item in data is dynamic but the API doesn't set the data as an array, i was trying to get the data from each item as i was yet doing for JSON arrays like this:

```
Dim options As JObject = JObject.Parse(json)
For Each opt As JObject In options("data")
    MsgBox(opt("name"))
Next
```

But it's not working in this case as as i said data is not an array...

So how could process data from that JSON as 89359 and 89360 are dynamic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `options("data")` is *declared* to be of type [`JToken`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm) while actually being of type [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm), so when you enumerate it you are actually enumerating its [`JProperty`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JProperty.htm) children.  But what you need are the [values](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JProperty_Value.htm) of those `JProperty` objects which are one level deeper in the hierarchy:

```
For Each jProperty As JProperty In options("data")
    Dim propertyName = jProperty.Name ' The "89359" names, in case you need them for some reason
    Dim opt As JObject = jProperty.Value
    Dim name As String = opt("name")  ' Cast the name to a String using the JToken implicit casting operator
    ' Use the name as required
    MsgBox(name)
Next
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SH2rxN).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the object that has the *name* property has other properties, what I would do is:

1. Create a class to represent the object with the *name* property
2. Deserialize the incoming data into a JObject
3. Get the "data" item of the JObject
4. Call ToObject from step 3 to a Dictionary(Of Integer, DataObject)

Here is an example:

```vb
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim input As String = "{""data"": {""89359"": {""name"": ""A"" }, ""89360"": {""name"": ""B"" } } }"
        Dim data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of JObject)(input)
        Dim dataItems = data.Item("data").ToObject(Of Dictionary(Of Integer, DataObject))

        For Each dataItem In dataItems
            Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}, DataObject.Name: {1}", dataItem.Key, dataItem.Value.name)
        Next
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module

Public Class DataObject

    Public Property name As String

    ' ...

End Class
```

Now the objects exist as an array via the `dataItems.Values` method.

Live Example: [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Fbloj1)